# How to process large files in webassembly in the browser?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I have an application (in C++) right now that validates files against a format specification. The files to be validated can be quite large (usually 200 MB to 2 GB, but I've also seen files up to 50 GB). For the file access, I'm using a memory mapped file right now as it's easy & fast.

I now want to be able to deploy this as a webpage where the user can drop their files onto & then it'll be validated. Due to the file size, it doesn't make sense to upload it, so I was thinking about validating it in the browser directly.

Due to code base also being used for command line applications & as libraries for native applications, I was thinking about a webassembly variant of the validation.

Is there an efficient way using webassembly to do the validation in the browser? The only thing that I found so far was loading it into a JS-Array and then make it available to C++ - but that's very slow & limited in size (at least the way I'm doing it). What's the recommended way for such a use-case?

Comment: Its not my forte, but maybe this will help [Rust - Wasm - Iterating over input file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67944469/2189130)

Comment: I have a similar use case. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I'll update here once I found one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, as I'm also searching for a viable solution. But I'll share what I have so far.

Here is a [repository](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/read_file_with_wasm) demonstrating how to read the first byte of a file with Rust and `wasm-bindgen`. Considering I've tried with 1GB files and got the result almost instantaneously, I assume it is not uploading the whole file to the browser.

Also, I'm pretty sure you've heard of [SQLite Wasm in the browser backed by the Origin Private File System](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sqlite-wasm-in-the-browser-backed-by-the-origin-private-file-system/) by now. That should be even more to the point as SQLite is written in C++.

From my (limited) understanding, once you have a FileHandle (whether from OPFS, a FileInput, or whatever) the rest is the same. So, the above solutions should work whether you're drag'n'dropping, using a File Upload, or reading from OPFS (my goal).

Essentially, in the example repo, the File Handle is passed to a worker (which has a sync access via `fileHandle.createSyncAccessHandle`)

```js
document.getElementById("file_picker").addEventListener(
        "change",
        function() {
            let file = this.files[0];
            myWorker.postMessage({ file: file, offset: BigInt(0) });
```

The worker is using the handle

```js
onmessage = async function(e) {
    let workerResult = read_at_offset_sync(
        e.data.file,
        e.data.offset,
    );
    postMessage(workerResult);
};
```

`read_at_offset_sync` is a function in Rust that reads the file using the web_sys crate/bridge. Another one of my assumptions would be that emscripten is providing something similar.

In the end, if you have a way to handle a [FileSystemSyncAccessHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemSyncAccessHandle), it will provide you with a [read()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemSyncAccessHandle/read) method which can read (parts of) the file directly, and with an offset, into a BufferArray. In Rust, it is [available](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.FileSystemSyncAccessHandle.html) with `wasm_bindgen` crate.